# iOS drawRect draw a border

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, drawrect

Hi I have draw a gradient in core graphic using drawRect function..

but I don't know how to draw a border to surround this view?

this is my code, could anyone help?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    NSArray *gradientColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor, [UIColor colorWithRed:90/255.0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1].CGColor, nil];

    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef) gradientColors, NULL);

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to draw a border around the view, try this:

```
UIBezierPath *border = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect];
[[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
[border setLineWidth:4.0];
[border stroke];
```

Use it at the end of drawRect: method.